# How to remove the entire dictionary from a list of dictionaries if a specific key is empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

So I have a list of dictionaries which has a lot of entries and looks something like that:

```
[{'Date': 'Jul 26', 'Time': '07:04:12', 'PID': '28886', 'Message': 'authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=NODEVssh ruser= rhost=207.243.167.114  user=root', 'Access Type': 'Failed', 'host/IP address': '207.243.167.114'}
{'Date': 'Jul 27', 'Time': '04:16:07', 'PID': '30999', 'Message': 'session opened for user cyrus by (uid=0)', 'Access Type': 'Success', 'host/IP address': ''}
{'Date': 'Jul 27', 'Time': '04:16:08', 'PID': '30999', 'Message': 'session closed for user cyrus', 'Access Type': '', 'host/IP address': ''}]
```

I want to remove the entire dictionary where "Access Type" == ''

I've tried this but this removes all the dictionaries as long as the value is blank in it but i only want specifically for "Access Type"

```
[d for d in data if all(d.values())]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Hint: you can use a simple list comprehension for this, or `filter` if you prefer

Comment: I've edited the question to show what i've tried

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension to check if `Access Type` is not empty:

```
[d for d in data if d["Access Type"]]
```

Or checking explicitly against `""`:

```
[d for d in data if d["Access Type"] != ""]
```

The first one works because empty strings `""` are considered `False` in a truth testing context. You can have a look at [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) from the documentation for more information.

Comment: Potentially `d.get("Access Type", "")!=""` will be safer option...

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski True, but I'll leave the OP to decide what option will be safer. The above demonstrates a solution the OP could follow.